# How to use series.isin with different sets for different values?

Tags: python, pandas

As you know I can do `df[df.column.isin(set)]` to get the part of the DataFrame where the column value is in that set. But now my source set is dependent on the value of column1. How do I make the function lookup a dictionary for the source set on the go, as it filters the dataframe?

let's say i have

```
dict1={'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,2],'c':[4,5,6]}
```

and my df looks like

```
column1  column2
a        4
b        2
c        6
```

and the new df should look like

```
column1  column2
b        2
c        6
```

Since 4 isn't in the list that 'a' points to in dict1.

`new_df = df[df.column2.isin(dict1[df.column1])]`
This gives me TypeError. I understand since i'm using pd.Series as keys and it's not hashable.

Comment: `dict1[df.column1]` is weird. `df.column1` is an entire column, it cannot be used as a key of a dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `isin` expect a sequence of values, and not a Series of sequences. Said differently it allows vectorization on keys but not on values.

So you have to use a non vectorized way here, for example:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['column2'] in dict1[x['column1']], axis=1)]
```

Comment: My kingdom for an `isin` vectorized on values...

Answer (score 2):

You could do with a list comprehension and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). In the comprehension, use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with logical AND (`&`) operator:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[df['column1'].eq(k) & df['column2'].isin(v)] for k, v in dict1.items()])
```

[out]

```
  column1  column2
1       b        2
2       c        6
```

---

Another approach would be to restructure your `dict` as a `DataFrame` and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_dict = pd.DataFrame([(k, i) for k, v in dict1.items() for i in v], columns=['column1', 'column2'])

df.merge(df_dict, how='inner', on=['column1', 'column2'])
```